# How to increase width of anchor tag inside li to li width

Tags: html, css

I have structure like this

```
  <div class='myClass'>
     <ul>
          <li>
               <a href="myfile.html">My link</a>
          </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

My `li` has a fixed with.
But `a` text is not always equal to `li` width
So the click able area is less than `li`.

I tried to fix it by increasing the width of the `a` but it is not working.

How can I achieve it.
I am using the following `css`

```
.tooltipinner ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   overflow-y: auto;
   padding: 0;
   width: 305px;
}
.tooltipinner ul li {
    background-color: #BBAEA5;
    background-image: url("../../Images/UIFiles/Menu/SubmenuBg.jpg");
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-top: 1px solid #C1BFBD;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    width: 199px;
}
.tooltipinner ul li:hover {
    background-color: #BBAEA5;
    background-image: url("../../Images/UIFiles/Menu/SubmenuBgHover.jpg");
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-top: 1px solid #C1BFBD;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.tooltipinner ul li a {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tooltipinner ul li a:link {
    color: #000000;
    min-width: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I was also trying to put a `div` inside `a` but `block` element can not be placed inside `a`.
How can I fixed this.

Here is a fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/qry45/2/
http://jsfiddle.net/qry45/4/

Comment: Provide a demo: http://jsbin.com

Comment: @Web_Designer I have created a fiddle and it is in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I´m not sure but if you apply `width:inherit;` to all inner a, it works

```
li {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

li a {
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: @krshekhar just add display: block;width: inherit; to .tooltipinner ul li a:link and you are done i have tested in firebug..

Comment: @krshekhar and other reason for not getting whole width is that your css have padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 4px; this three rules for .tooltipinner ul li so anchor will take entire width but with padding to that three side.

Comment: @Niraj : Can you paste what you are doing or share some fiddle to take a look.

Comment: @DipeshParmar i got it working from below answer, i.e using display:block on my anchor tag.

Comment: @Niraj : Glad that you found the solution.  Cheers

Answer (score 11):

Something like this in your CSS:

```
.myClass li a {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Block elements can be placed inside inline elements (`<a>`, `<span>`, etc.) if you're using the HTML5 doctype, and if you set `display: block;` on the `<a>` element:

```
.myClass li a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @Shekhar What you're trying to accomplish can be done with a whole lot less CSS. Here's an improved demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qry45/6/

Comment: This is indeed working for me. Great work. Thanks man. Saved my time.

Comment: the display:block part is key and usually overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.myClass li a {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: auto;
    justify-content: center;    
}
```

Display flex with flex-basis: auto will take whole li container and justfy content will center text. This work on ie 11 too.